# Как разделить строку при встрече одного из заданных символов?

Tags: python

Как разделить строку при первой встрече одного из этих символов:

```
' ', ')', 'a', '3'
```

Кроме как перебором предложения по буквам ничего придумать не могу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

strings = re.split(r"[ \)a3]", input_str)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только параметры поменять местами надо =)

Comment: @helldrg, спасибо, исправил )